# Moving texture OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to implement a sprite of 8 columns and 8 rows in OpenGL ES 2.0
I made appear the first imagen but I cant figure out how to translate the Texture matrix in OpenGL ES 2.0 , the equivalent of the code in OpenGL 1.0 that I am looking is

```
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.2f, 0f);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
```

This are the matrix that I am using atm

```
/**
 * Store the model matrix. This matrix is used to move models from object space (where each model can be thought
 * of being located at the center of the universe) to world space.
 */
private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

/**
 * Store the view matrix. This can be thought of as our camera. This matrix transforms world space to eye space;
 * it positions things relative to our eye.
 */
private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

/** Store the projection matrix. This is used to project the scene onto a 2D viewport. */
private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

/** Allocate storage for the final combined matrix. This will be passed into the shader program. */
private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

/** 
 * Stores a copy of the model matrix specifically for the light position.
 */
private float[] mLightModelMatrix = new float[16];
```

My Vertex shader

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;       // A constant representing the combined     model/view/projection matrix.                  
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;        // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.              

attribute vec4 a_Position;      // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.                             
attribute vec3 a_Normal;        // Per-vertex normal information we will pass in.      
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.       

varying vec3 v_Position;        // This will be passed into the fragment shader.                            
varying vec3 v_Normal;          // This will be passed into the fragment shader.  
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // This will be passed into the fragment shader.            

// The entry point for our vertex shader.  
void main()                                                     
{                                                         
    // Transform the vertex into eye space.     
    v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);                 

    // Pass through the texture coordinate.
    v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;                                      

    // Transform the normal's orientation into eye space.
    v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));

    // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
    // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;                               
}
```

My Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;        // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                            // precision in the fragment shader.
    uniform vec3 u_LightPos;        // The position of the light in eye space.
    uniform sampler2D u_Texture;    // The input texture.

    varying vec3 v_Position;        // Interpolated position for this fragment.
    varying vec3 v_Normal;          // Interpolated normal for this fragment.
    varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.

    // The entry point for our fragment shader.
    void main()                         
    {                              
        // Will be used for attenuation.
      float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);                  

        // Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex.
     vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position);                 

        // Calculate the dot product of the light vector and vertex normal. If the normal and light vector are
        // pointing in the same direction then it will get max illumination.
     float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.0);                                                                                

        // Add attenuation. 
     diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance)));

     // Add ambient lighting
     diffuse = diffuse + 0.7;  

        // Multiply the color by the diffuse illumination level and texture value to get final output color.
     gl_FragColor = (diffuse * texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));                                          
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to perform transformations to the texture co-ordinates yourself, you could do this in one of four places:

- Apply the transformation to your raw model data.
- Apply the transformation in the CPU (not recommended unless you have good reason as this is what vertex shaders are for).
- Apply the transformation in the vertex shader (recommended).
- Apply the transformation in the fragment shader.

If you are going to apply a translation to the texture coordinates the most flexible way will be to use your maths library to create a translation matrix and pass the new matrix to your vertex shader as a uniform (the same way you pass the mMVPMatrix and mLightModelMatrix).
You can then multiply the translation matrix by the texture coordinate in the vertex shader and output the result as a varying vector.

Vertex Shader:

```
texture_coordinate_varying = texture_matrix_uniform * texture_coordinate_attribute;
```

Fragment Shader:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture_sampler, texture_coordinate_varying);
```

Please note: Your GLES 1.0 code does not actually perform a translation as you surrounded it with a push and pop.

Comment: I am not convinced your recommendations are correct for this case: Doing the translation on the CPU for this case would simply mean creating 8 floats with very simple operations and pass the 8 floats to the GPU. Doing it on the GPU means creating a matrix of 16 floats on the CPU using a much more complex system (still simple though) and sending 16 floats to the GPU and add an extra matrix multiplication on the vertex shader. I am not arguing as if you needed the transform on some large object this is definitely the way to go but not for this case.

Comment: Thanks OFE for your reply It is really helpfull, I get your point, the problem is that I am new in shaders and I dont know how to translate the solution to my shader, I updated the question with my shaders , could you please explain it a little more if you dont mind?